# Почему в первом случае код работает, а во втором я получаю OutOfMemoryError?

Tags: java, outofmemoryerror

Возник вопрос о `heap memory`. Так вот обратите внимание на жирный курсив. в 1-м варианте все нормально работает. Но вот во втором выскакивает:

> OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Кто подскажет, почему?

Вот код:

```
public class idea_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("S:\\idea test\\src\\file.txt")); 
        ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();  
        
        (1)          
        String s;                                           
        while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null){
            strings.add(s);                                                     
        }

        (2)
        String s = reader.readLine();                                           
        while (s != null){
            strings.add(s);                                                     
        }

        reader.close();                                                         
        String[] strings1 = strings.toArray(new String[strings.size()]);        
        Arrays.sort(strings1);                                                  
        for (String s1 : strings1) {
            System.out.println(s1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

В **первом** случае мы крутимся в цикле и при каждой итерации вызываем

```
reader.readLine()
```

после чего проверяем `s` на `null`, если все строки файла были прочитаны(`(s = reader.readLine()) != null` == `false`), то благополучно вываливаемся из цикла.

Во **втором** же случае у нас получается бесконечный цикл, так как мы **один раз** вызвали

```
reader.readLine()
```

а далее бесконечно крутимся в цикле (так как `s != null` - истинно всегда, ведь мы же не меняем `s`), добавляя в `ArrayList` одни и те же значения, что и приводит к `OutOfMemoryError`

Comment: метод readLine() при каждой итерации опускается на одну строку вниз?

Comment: да, метод readLine() при каждой итерации опускается на одну строку вниз